# Drop duplicates with time series condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table with ship destinations.
I wish to dedupe the destination but according to Time condition.
Meaning, for example, ship1 has changed direction from HK to SH, and change from SH to HK, every time it changes destination, it should be recorded, doesn't matter HK was a destination or not.

```
A   Destination Time
Ship1   HK  1
Ship1   HK  2
Ship1   BKK 3
Ship2   SH  4
Ship2   SH  5
Ship2   QD  6
Ship1   HK  7
Ship2   QD  8
Ship2   HK  9
```

So the ideal result is:

```
A   Destination
Ship1   HK
Ship1   BKK
Ship2   SH
Ship2   QD
Ship1   HK
Ship2   HK
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
df.loc[~df.groupby('A',sort=False)['Destination'].apply(lambda x: x.eq(x.shift())), ['A','Destination']]
```

**output**

```
        A   Destination
0   Ship1   HK
2   Ship1   BKK
3   Ship2   SH
5   Ship2   QD
6   Ship1   HK
8   Ship2   HK
```

Comment: compare the shift of self?

Comment: We are comparing the next row of the same ship & we don't want that to be same as the current row.

Comment: Thanks, I saw your last version with Time column, I sorta need that column too.. let me try with my real data set

Comment: if you need 'Time' column as well, remove `, ['A','Destination']` from the code.

Answer (score 2):

A variant of moy's solution:

```
B = df.groupby(['A'],sort=False).Destination.shift()
df.loc[~df.Destination.eq(B)]

      A Destination Time
0   Ship1   HK  1
2   Ship1   BKK 3
3   Ship2   SH  4
5   Ship2   QD  6
6   Ship1   HK  7
8   Ship2   HK  9
```